# How to avoid redirecting twice (React)?

Tags: reactjs

I need to eliminate twice redirecting. 
From App.js it goes to Product.js and then i need to redirect to /notfound. It works but goes twice there, even through i implemented Switch there.
Where do i do a mistake? I have only seen advices to put Switch there, but it does not help.

There is my code:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Products from './Products';
import NotFound from './NotFound';
import Home from "./Home";

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
                    <Route path="/notfound" component={NotFound} />
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Product.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Products extends Component {

    state = {
        toDashboard: false,
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            toDashboard: true
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);

        if (this.state.toDashboard === true) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Redirect to={{
                            pathname: '/notfound', state: { id: '123' }
                        }} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Products</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Products;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `history.push` as follows:

```
if (this.state.toDashboard === true) {
  this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/notfound', state: { id: 123 }})
}
```

Comment: But i need to insert that "state: { id: 123}" as prop, i have no idea how to do that in case you mentioned.

Comment: Please check updated answer. Also check https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation

Comment: I had to rearrange it and it works. Remove state and put this history.push directly inside handleSubmit method. Thanks!